# Eclipse Import - java Collections can not be resolved error

Tags: java, eclipse, collections

Error happens in the code below.

`Arrays.sort(a, Collections.reverseOrder());`

It says "Collections can not be resolved."

Attempts to solve:

(1) Added the import at the top, but it still says "import java.util.Collections can not be resolved."

`import java.util.Collections;`

(2) Collection import works fine though

`import java.util.Collection;`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609538/how-to-fix-collectiontype-import-issues-in-eclipse

Comment: Are you using a jdk with version prior to 7?

Comment: Is your project still pointing to a valid Java Runtime?

Comment: could you please post your code here

Comment: It would be helpful to include the Eclipse version and the Java version. Perhaps, the Eclipse version is too old for the used Java version and fails to process some of the class files.

Answer (score 1):

For me the "solution" was to add an "additional" JRE (Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Add) in Eclipse (version 2021-06, 4.20.0) and switch to that.

In Linux you can just add e.g. `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64` and additionally `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64`.

Switching back to the JRE where Eclipse showed the errors was also fine. The error message stayed away.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are not somehow referencing or implicitly using a Java Runtime that's older than Collections allow.

Comment: That would be older than Java 2. I doubt that this is the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all imports that you have and press CTRl+Shift+O
It will re-import everything you need
Solved the same issue for me